# Convert doc and docx to PDF in Python (for all OSes)

Tags: python, pdf, ms-word

I have a litany of doc files that I need to convert to PDF. I'm familiar with `docx2pdf`, which works like a charm, but only with docx files. Is there an automated way via Python that will convert doc files to Python, or maybe "just" doc to docx files?

Comment: Rendering rich text files, such as doc, docx and PDF are complex tasks, that rely on the core of multi-megabyte programs. Some libraries simply build the core of these programs inside themselves (and thus, become multi-megabyte) - other than that, a cross-platform program capable of rendering doc files and generating PDFs is libreoffice - you can search recipes on calling libreoffice a headless from the CLI, to convert your docs, and make the call from Python with s"subprocess".